# Macro Copy and paste HTML file contents to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of file locations. All of these contain .shtml extensions. I would like to use a macro to use the file location of each cell to copy the html code within each file, and then paste the results in cell to the right.

Comment: Is there a macro/vba that you've written that you are having problems with or do you want to someone to write it for you?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post relevant code otherwise your question is off-topic here.

Comment: If you're not sure where to start, fire up the macro recorder & do what you want. Fiddle with it from there.

Comment: You have to be careful with this approach, as there are character limit that you can put into a cell. So you may end up splitting the html into multiple columns.